# Change status code in HTTP header without affecting return data in Yii 1 Restful API

Tags: php, exception, yii, http-headers

I want to return data with the HTTP error code in Yii 1. So I used the following way to get the data:

```
  $code = (0 == $ex->getCode()) ? (isset($ex->statusCode) ? $ex->statusCode : 500) : $ex->getCode();
            $this->setOutputError($ex->getMessage());
            $this->setOutputCode($code);
```

When I use it this way API returns data with 200 error code as below:

[image]

But I want to change header status 200, so I threw exception for this, then output data also changed. I want to change only the header status.

```
$code = (0 == $ex->getCode()) ? (isset($ex->statusCode) ? $ex->statusCode : 500) : $ex->getCode();
            $this->setOutputError($ex->getMessage());
            $this->setOutputCode($code);

            throw new CHttpException(400, 'Bad Request');
```

[image]

Comment: You can set in your code before `return` statement `\Yii::$app->response->statusCode = XXX` where `XXX` is a new status code. You have put `CHttpException` in your code - are you sure you are using Yii 2 and not Yii 1?

Comment: @Bizley sorry  Yii 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii 1.1 does not have response abstraction, you need to use `http_response_code()` to change response status code:

```
$code = (0 == $ex->getCode()) ? (isset($ex->statusCode) ? $ex->statusCode : 500) : $ex->getCode();
$this->setOutputError($ex->getMessage());
$this->setOutputCode($code);

http_response_code(400);
```

Alternatively you may also use `header()`, but this is more tricky.